# asp.net project (privacy preserving multi keyword ranked search over encrypted cloud data)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Currently I'm having this issue.

I have the complete source code file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqCNfHpYEJlQUJLQm9ubUQ4c3c/view?usp=sharin).

Every time I run the project I get this [error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxqCNfHpYEJlemZld050VnBOODA&authuser=0).

Does anybody know why?

Comment: If you are worried about down votes, than make sure to only ask questions that meet our minimum quality requirements.

Comment: i am not really... its just that i lose many of my features... also please share if you have any idea related to the topic that could solve my issue...

Comment: This is a perfect example of why it's necessary to include relevant code or error messages in the question rather than using external links. Now that these links are broken, this question is completely meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could happened for some reasons

**1.- web.config**

You have 2 `web.config` one on you root app folder, and other on the admin folder.

**2.- IIS configuration**

bad IIS congiruation, you should create virtual directory and point it to the actual project.

**3.- Chanign Auth**

**from** `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`
**to** `<authentication mode="None"/>`

also check that the database file you have is obsolete or not...

Comment: thanks for taking interest in helping me... i still have doubts... 1. do i ave to remove the second web.config? 2.please elaborate this step, like what i should do... thanks in advance.